# Popup inside a for loop not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I need to show a popup every time I get a line of data back from my AJAX post request. The code is below. I am sure it works because using an alert gives me the correct output

```
var url = "http://localhost/test/";

                 $.post(url+"loop_messages.php",{id: id},function(data, status){
                 //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                 var json = JSON.parse(data);
                 for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {
                 //alert("data was" +json[i].message);
                 $("#myPopup").html(json[i].message);
                 $("#myPopup").css("display", "block");
                 $( "#myPopup" ).show();
                 //$("#myPopup").popup( "open");
                 }
    });
```

Somewhere in my HTML body I have:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="open-popup" style="display: none;"></div>
```

The popup never comes up. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean, `#myPopup` is unique, so why do you try to set the content and show it over and over again in a loop?

Comment: Try to remove "style" attribute from your element and use $("#myPopup").hide() to actually hide it. That might be an issue.

Comment: @eisbehr this is part of a mobile app in Phonegap  I have a table in my database that holds some messages. (there is a reason I don't want to use push for these) Each time the user opens the app. I check if a user has seen a message or not. My post request decides which messages a user has not yet seen and must show them and set them as seen when they are shown. myPopup is a div i need to act as my popup for the message he has not yet seen.

Comment: But your code would only show the last message to the user. This doesn't make sense to me?!